# What does the command "users" do?

Tags: users

What does the command "users" do?

I don't really get it :( "groups" lists all groups. But "users" not all users.

I hope you can help me :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It prints the users who are logged in. It is a stripped down version of tools like `w` and `who`.

```
NAME
       users - print the user names of users currently logged in to the
       current host

SYNOPSIS
       users [OPTION]... [FILE]

DESCRIPTION
       Output who is currently logged in according to FILE.  If FILE is
       not specified, use /var/run/utmp.  /var/log/wtmp as FILE is com‐
       mon.

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit
```

Source: `man users`

---

`groups` does ***not*** list all groups, it lists the groups that the current user is in. Perhaps some `man groups` would help you too :)

Comment: thanks! sorry I'm quite new. Since now I always use man. I promise :P

Answer (score 1):

Whenever wondering about what a command does and can do; check its *man page*

How? Try this in a shell.

```
$ man command-name
```

Doing this for the *users* command will tell you

```
users  -  print the user names of users currently logged in to the
          current hos
```

Comment: @Oli I lost the race it seems :-)